# AzureRM App Service deploying started failing today

Tags: azure, azure-devops

All of my builds started failing today with a new version of AzureRM App Service deploy version 2.1.3.

I use Hosted pool for Team Services (Windows).

```
2016-11-11T13:02:36.2644641Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy AzureRM App Service: xxx
2016-11-11T13:02:36.2744703Z ==============================================================================
2016-11-11T13:02:36.2744703Z Task         : Azure App Service Deploy
2016-11-11T13:02:36.2744703Z Description  : Update Azure App Service using Web Deploy / Kudu REST APIs
2016-11-11T13:02:36.2744703Z Version      : 2.1.3
2016-11-11T13:02:36.2744703Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2016-11-11T13:02:36.2744703Z Help         : [More Information](https://aka.ms/azurermwebdeployreadme)
2016-11-11T13:02:36.2744703Z ==============================================================================
2016-11-11T13:02:36.3044674Z ##[error]File not found: 'C:\a\_tasks\AzureRmWebAppDeploy_xxx\2.1.3\azurermwebappdeployment.js'
2016-11-11T13:02:36.3074644Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy AzureRM App Service: xxx
```

Yesterday deployments worked correctly (version 2.0.7).

Any ideas what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Meanwhile I can use work-around: deploy with Azure App Service: Classic which is newly tagged as Deprecated (and much much slower).

Thank you in advance for any help.

**Issue is now fixed according to https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3074 and my tests.**

Comment: I got the same error a few minutes ago, and we have a demo in 20 minutes. It seems that my organization does not have access to Azure App Service: Classic. I tried https://manage.windowsazure.com, Is that the same that you are using?

Comment: I have seen the problem myself just recently. Version 2.1.3 as well.

Comment: I use VSTS (*.visualstudio.com). If you want to deploy your app you need to modify your build config: instead of Azure App Service Deploy use Azure App Service Classic: Deprecated. Configuration is very similar. You get only a warning message in log that's it's deprecated.

Comment: I am not sure that classic deploy can be used in every situation, it probably depends on how your apps are set up in Azure. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3074

Comment: If you use App service (plans) I believe there is no difference. There are not classic and new (ARM) versions. The same apply for scheduler jobs (web jobs). I use VSTS only for App services, Web jobs and NUGET packages. Workaround works for me but I'm pretty sure you're right - it cannot be used in all cases probably.

Comment: Thanks for github link. Good to know we are not alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hacky solution which may or may not work but can be tried. Go to the BD/RD where this task is getting used. Change anything and capture the save BD/RD call using the network tab in Chrome. See the request JSON, there you will have versionSpec field for the AzureRMWebApp which will be set to 2.1.3 or *.

Replay the call using some REST client like POSTMAN and set the versionSpec to 2.1.2 or whichever version was working for you. This can be done only through APIs. And don't change anything from UI since it will again put the latest version in the JSON.

I would advise to use POSTMAN + POSTMAN Interceptor chrome addons for this since it makes capturing and replaying calls very easy and also allows you to change the request JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the build agent has silently upgraded the AzureRmWebAppDeploy task to 2.1.4 and it works again. I don't know if it is because I recreated the deploy step in the release configuration or not.